# How to resize the widgets in the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard-widget

I wish to enlarge the widgets in my dashboard, because I find it quite uncomfortable to see the contents of the dictionary widget in that small box.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is currently not possible to resize Dashboard widgets yourself.**

However, the developer of the widget can make their widget resizable. [This Apple Developer Documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/Resizing.html) describes the process by which developers can make their widget resizable, however it is uncommon for a widget to be made resizable:

> Try to limit using live-resizing to cases where it is absolutely necessary. If your content can be shown in a fixed, simple user interface, do so.

Answer (score 0):

no unfortunately thats not possible, they are bounded to whatever size or shape they came in!

Answer (score -2):

No that's not true you can do it easily you just click on the background of the dashboard (the bit to the left of the trash bin works & it's often a double finger tap depending on how you set your trackpad up) then you choose dock preferences from the pop up box & move the magnification slider up :)

Comment: The question doesn't mention the Dock at all. It's about Dashboard Widgets… System Prefs > Mission Control > Dashboard  [obsolete since Catalina].

Comment: Ahh that's me getting my dock & dashboard muddled up then :-/